# What is the cohomological explanation for the Condorcets voting paradox?

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology

according to the [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/davidcorfield/show/intuitions+about+cohomology) entry on the [Condorcet Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_paradox) in social choice  (that is voting preferences may be circular even if voters preferences are not) has a cohomological explanation - what is it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is nothing serious - Ghist only noticed the existence of cycles in the set of voted alternatives. If you are interested in algebraic methods of  the theory of voting, I advise you to see the results of V.Danilov (e.g., http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.2888.pdf and previous papers).